# React / Relay server side rendering and SEO friendly application

Tags: reactjs, seo, graphql, relay, isomorphic-relay

What is the most reliable way/approach to build React/Relay/GraphQL SEO friendly application with server side rendering ?

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I wrote [`isomorphic-relay`](https://github.com/denvned/isomorphic-relay) and [`isomorphic-relay-router`](https://github.com/denvned/isomorphic-relay-router) to solve exactly that problem. And I still support and update them, as they are still very actual. Personally I use these libraries in my projects, and other people also use them in production.

Answer (score 0):

I would checkout [Next.js](https://nextjs.org) together with [relay-nextjs](https://reverecre.github.io/relay-nextjs/) package.

Next.js solves SSR,the relay-nextjs package as a glue for Relay.
Also, I recommend check on this medium.com [article](https://yashmahalwal.medium.com/relay-modern-ssr-and-next-js-e0a77ec3d7ea)